# jQuery validation - no field highlight

Tags: jquery, user-interface, validation

I want to use the jQuery validation plugin, but I don't want it to add a class to the actual input box, rather just display the message next to it.

Any ideas how to disable the field highlighting?

Comment: do you mean you don't want to add class required to the field but you want to still show the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to the field to be required without adding class you can add a rule

```
$("#myinput").rules("add", {
   required: true
});
```